# Correct way to make meta box with more than one meta field secure

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, metabox

I used several online tutorials to make a plugin that has a meta box that contains more than one field. It seems to work fine and save the data however I just want to ensure that my plugin is secure. The code is below. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
 /*
  Typical Header info
 */

 /* Artists Galleries Function that sets up
 our custom post type and registers it */

function artist_galleries_cpt() {

$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Artist Galleries', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Artist Gallery', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Post'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add New Artist Gallery'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Artist Gallery'),
'new_item' => __('New Artist Gallery'),
'view_item' => __('View Artist Gallery'),
'search_items' => __('Search Artist Galleries'),
'not_found' =>  __('No Artist Galleries found'),
'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Artist Galleries found in Trash'),
'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'galleries_test'),
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => 5,
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
'has_archive' => true
);

// Custom Post Type Registers Here
register_post_type('artist_galleries',$args);
}

add_action('init', 'artist_galleries_cpt');


/* Function that changes the default messages
 seen when working on our custom post type */

function artist_galleries_updated_messages( $messages ) {

global $post, $post_ID;
$messages['artist_galleries'] = array(
0 => '',
1 => sprintf( __('Artist Gallery updated. <a href="%s">View Artist Gallery</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
2 => __('Custom field updated.'),
3 => __('Custom field deleted.'),
4 => __('Arist Gallery updated.'),
5 => isset($_GET['revision']) ? sprintf( __('Artist Gallery restored to revision from %s'), wp_post_revision_title( (int) $_GET['revision'], false ) ) : false,
6 => sprintf( __('Artist Gallery published. <a href="%s">View Artist Gallery</a>'), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
7 => __('Artist Gallery saved.'),
8 => sprintf( __('Artist Gallery submitted. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview Artist Gallery</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
9 => sprintf( __('Artist Gallery scheduled for: <strong>%1$s</strong>. <a target="_blank" href="%2$s">Preview Artist Gallery</a>'), date_i18n( __( 'M j, Y @ G:i' ), strtotime( $post->post_date ) ), esc_url( get_permalink($post_ID) ) ),
10 => sprintf( __('Artist Gallery draft updated. <a target="_blank" href="%s">Preview Artist Gallery</a>'), esc_url( add_query_arg( 'preview', 'true', get_permalink($post_ID) ) ) ),
);
return $messages;
 }
 add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'artist_galleries_updated_messages' );

 /* Function that will add our custom
 meta boxes to the admin screen */

function add_artist_info_meta_box() {

 // Add Meta Box Function for Products that Artist Sells
add_meta_box(
'artist-info-meta-box', // Unique ID
esc_html__( 'Artist Info', 'example' ), // Title
'artist_info_meta_box', // Callback function
'artist_galleries', // Admin page (or post type)
'side', // Context
'default' // Priority
);
}

// Add meta box using the 'add_meta_boxes' hook.
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_artist_info_meta_box' );

 /* Function that will display our custom
 meta boxes to the screen */

function artist_info_meta_box() {

// $post is already set, and contains an object: the WordPress post
global $post;

$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

// Set our field variables
   $products_sold = isset( $values['products_sold'] ) ? $values['products_sold'][0] : '';
    $website = isset( $values['website'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['website'][0] ) : '';
    $address = isset( $values['address'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['address'][0] ) : '';
    $phone = isset( $values['phone'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['phone'][0] ) : '';
    $email = isset( $values['email'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['email'][0] ) : '';
    $hours = isset( $values['hours'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['hours'][0] ) : '';

    // We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.
    wp_nonce_field( 'artist_info_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="products-sold">Products Sold</label> </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="products_sold" id="products_sold" value="<?php echo $products_sold; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
  <label for="website">Website</label> </p>
  <p>
  <input type="text" name="website" id="website" value="<?php echo $website;    ?>" />
  </p>

  <p>
  <label for="address">Address</label> </p>
  <p>
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo $address;   ?>" />
  </p>

<p>
  <label for="phone">Phone</label> </p>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />
</p>

 <p>
 <label for="email">Email</label> </p>
 <p>
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
 </p>

 <p>
 <label for="hours">Hours</label> </p>
  <p>
 <input type="text" name="hours" id="hours" value="<?php echo $hours; ?>" />
 </p>
 <?php
}?>
  <?php
   function artist_info_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
     // Bail if we're doing an auto save
     if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

      // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
       if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce(    $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'artist_info_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

// now we can actually save the data
$allowed = array(
    'a' => array( // on allow a tags
        'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute
    )
);

  // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
if( isset( $_POST['products_sold'] ) )
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'products_sold', wp_kses( $_POST['products_sold'], $allowed ) );

if( isset( $_POST['website'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'website', wp_kses( $_POST['website'], $allowed ) );

if( isset( $_POST['address'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', wp_kses( $_POST['address'], $allowed ) );

if( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'phone', wp_kses( $_POST['phone'], $allowed ) );

if( isset( $_POST['email'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'email', wp_kses( $_POST['email'], $allowed ) );

if( isset( $_POST['hours'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hours', wp_kses( $_POST['hours'], $allowed ) );


 }
add_action( 'save_post', 'artist_info_meta_box_save' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say that there is no web application 100% secure.

That being said, you are using the nonce correctly. The function you are using, `update_post_meta()`, will sql-scape the data as it uses insert/update methods of [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). So, there is no risk for most common security problemas.

What you should take care, I think, is data validation, and you are doing that incorrectly. You pass all meta fields values to `wp_kses()` function and you allow `<a>` elements in all the fields. I think that is not what you want; for example, I think you don't want to allow `<a>` element in the email or phone fields.

Instead of pass all values to `wp_kses()` you should do a specific data validation and/or sanitization for each one. For example:

```
if( isset( $_POST['products_sold'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'products_sold', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['products_sold'] ) );
}
if( isset( $_POST['website'] ) ) {
     //Leave as it was to allow website as <a href="...">...</a>
     //update_post_meta( $post_id, 'website', wp_kses( $_POST['website'], $allowed ) );
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'website', esc_url_raw( $_POST['website'] ) );
}

if( isset( $_POST['address'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['address'] ) );
}

if( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phone'] ) );
}

if( isset( $_POST['email'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'email', sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] ) );
}

if( isset( $_POST['hours'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hours', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['hours'] ) );
}
```

You could go further and define a custom validation function that will be performed every time a specific meta field is updated/created. For example:

```
//Create and define the `sanitize_phone_meta` filter:
add_filter( 'sanitize_post_meta_phone', 'sanitize_phone_meta' );
function ssanitize_phone_meta( $phone ) {

    //Perform whatever validation you want for phone value
    //For example, if you only want the phone format 000-0000-0000
    if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $phone)) {
        // $phone is valid
        return $phone;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then, in the `save_post` hook:

```
if( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
     $clean_phone = sanitize_meta( 'phone', $_POST['phone'], 'post' );
     if( $clean_phone !== false ) {
         update_post_meta( $post_id, 'phone', $clean_phone );
     } else {
         //Do something when the phone format is not what you expect
     }
}
```

This way, a little more work is required, but the phone meta field will be sanitized against the defined filter every time the phone meta is created/updated from any where without the need of writing the sanitzation code again.

More in:

- [Wordpress Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)
- [Sanitize meta reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_meta)

Comment: To confirm, I shouldn't use `wp_kses` at all, correct? Instead I should use `esc_url_raw` just for the website? I also found out that I should put init in before I register my post type.

Comment: You should use `wp_kses` if you want to allow HTML and want to control which HTML are allowed. `esc_url_raw` will make a URL safe for database queries but dosen't check if it is a valid URL.